# programa que compare 10 digitos y los ordene de menor a mayor en java

Tags: java

tengo un trabajo de mi universidad que va de un programa que compare 10 digitos y los ordene de menor a mayor, lo he logrado hacer pero solo con que compare 3 digitos, alguien me puede ayudar a organizar correctamente para comparar correctamente los 10 digitos correctamente...

help... :(

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n1,n2,n3;

    System.out.println("ingrese el numero: ");
    n1=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("ingrese el numero: ");
    n2=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("ingrese el numero: ");
    n3=sc.nextInt();
    
    if(n1>n2&n2>n3){
        System.out.println("Los numeros ordenados de menor a mayor: ");
        System.out.println(n1);
        System.out.println(n2);
        System.out.println(n3);
    }else if(n1>n3&n3>n2){
        System.out.println("Los numeros ordenados de menor a mayor: ");
        System.out.println(n1);
        System.out.println(n3);
        System.out.println(n2);
    }else if(n2>n1&n3>n2){
        System.out.println("Los numeros ordenados de menor a mayor: ");
        System.out.println(n2);
        System.out.println(n1);
        System.out.println(n3);
    }else if(n2>n3&n3>n1){
        System.out.println("Los numeros ordenados de menor a mayor: ");
        System.out.println(n2);
        System.out.println(n3);
        System.out.println(n1);
    }else if(n3>n1&n1>n2){
        System.out.println("Los numeros ordenados de menor a mayor: ");
        System.out.println(n3);
        System.out.println(n1);
        System.out.println(n2);
    }else if(n3>n2&n2>n1){
        System.out.println("Los numeros ordenados de menor a mayor: ");
        System.out.println(n1);
        System.out.println(n2);
        System.out.println(n3);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Bueno, ya entendiste como comparar variables.. ahora, en lugar de usar una variable para cada ingreso, usa una lista (o array, o algo asi) donde guardar los valores que el usuario vaya ingresando...

Answer (score 1):

No estoy seguro que te piden o que podes o no utilizar, yo en lo particular lo que hice es crear una lista vacía, un for para pedir al usuaria que introduzca un número n veces, y se agregue a la lista, luego con la collections y un sort lo ordene, y por último una salida a pantalla de la lista ordenada. Espero te sirva y por las dudas si es para un trabajo en concreto la próxima vez coloca limitaciones o condiciones del problema. Suerte.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    ArrayList list_numbers = new ArrayList();

    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++){
        System.out.println("ingrese un numero entero: ");
        list_numbers.add(sc.nextInt());
    }
    
    Collections.sort(list_numbers);
    System.out.println("Los numeros ordenados de menor a mayor: ");
    System.out.println(list_numbers);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con algo así, utiliza mejor los ciclo for para este tipo de operaciones repetitivas.
En ves de crear varios ciclos para leer cada número, utiliza el ciclo for que te ahorrara tiempo ya que sirve para realizar tareas repetitivas, en este caso leer N cantidad de números.
Esto lo vas almacenando en un arreglo que es una variable tipo array que te permite almacenar N cantidad de espacios o números en tu caso. Con el segundo ciclo for los vas leyendo donde i=N al número que previamente ya has leido o almacenado. En este segundo ciclo solo vas recorriendo el arreglo y mostrando los resultados

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] miArreglo = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("Ingrese el número en la posición " + (i) + " :");
        miArreglo[i] = entrada.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.print("Menor a mayor:[");
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(arreglo[i] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.print("]\n");
}
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple).

Comment: Gracias @gbianchi